# Downloading query with composer?

Tags: jquery, composer-php

I wish to install jquery with composer. Here is how I've done it:

```
"require": {
    "components/jquery": "1.9.*"
},
```

This has created a components folder with jquery in it.

My question is:

1. Can I specify where query is downloaded to, I'd prefer it to go in public/src
2. The above downloads loads of things like require-built, require.js, jquery-migrate. Is there a way to specify just downloading jquery?

Comment: `components` is a collection of assets pre-loaded to be combined via requirejs.  Personally I have stopped using it since the inconsistent nature of requiring assets and the difficultly of adding personal assets to the build made for some pretty messy projects.

Answer (score 1):

1. That components/jquery package uses RobLoach/component-installer to put the files somewhere useful, and the README file has explanations how to affect this: https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer
2. No, if you want to use this package for jquery, these are dependencies, even if you don't need them.

You should probably look into "Bower" or "Component", which are package manager for frontend dependencies like Javascripts.